# SonarQube – Error: Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile

Tags: sonarqube

The following is our SonarQube Build Environment.

```
* SonarQube Server Version – 5.1
* Build Machine OS – Windows -7 64-Bit
* Sonar Runner on Client Host Version – 2.4
```

Error:

> 15:02:23.263 WARN  - Sonargraph: ProjectxMR Development Console
> [com.project.hme.xmR] is not processed, since no Sonargraph rules are
> activated in current SonarQube quality profile.

Kindly help me to resolve the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is a warning, not an error, and it is simply telling you that the Sonargraph report (if any) will not be processed. Why? Because you haven't added any Sonargraph rules to the quality profile (most likely the default Java profile) being used for the analysis.

If you're not passing in a Sonargraph report, then you can consider this ignore-able noise caused by the fact that you have the Sonargraph plugin installed without using it.

Comment: Can I disable this warning anyhow per configuration? It makes our CI red all the time, although it is only a warning.

Comment: Try raising an issue in the Sonargraph community @beseder.